# how is language translation done in facebook?

Tags: translation

i would like to know, how is the language translation done in facebook ?
Are they using google translate, or any licensed software ?

I want to enable language translation in my website, and i want similar to that of facebook.

How Can this be done, if at all possible ?

Comment: Especially pirate! Ar my hearties!

Comment: At least some of the translation is user-contributed (the Latin translation is entirely user-contributed).

Comment: Its ok, i want to know, what is the process they are using, for translation? Are they using something like google translate internally?

Answer (score 1):

Google has good translation API that will convert your text in to given language. However if you want to translate a larger paragraph you need to go for human translation. Because Google translation is not converting grammar of other languages. Now there are good services available that allow automate the human translation like http://mygengo.com/

Comment: I hope google also converts the grammar of other languages. I saw it working in google translate for languages like french.

Comment: It is working but it is not 100% accurate to blindly publish it on the web

Comment: But google accounts for a faster translation, and moreover its free. Cant beat it. So most of the users choose google for language translation. Now, my question is: does facebook employ google for language translation?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's partner for search and for translate functions is Microsoft Bing.

To use it similarly you need to use the API provided, see 'Translator' here at their Developer page:
http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center

Source of my info: several websites including
http://translation-blog.multilizer.com/how-to-use-facebook-translate-button/